# when <textarea> character count reaches 30 enable <button>

Tags: jquery, html

i want to display the number (30) below my `<textarea>` to count the characters inside it.

it then decreases as characters are being typed/pressed.

im using `$j` as required by Wordpress to avoid conflict.

this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JGmcN/1/

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){

$j("#textArea").keyup(function(){
    count = $(this); // insert values here

    $j("#charNum").text(30);  // Display 30
    if ($j(this).val().length >= 30 )  // if the value length is >= 30 then...
    {
      $j("#charNum").text(30 - count.val().length));  //display while subtracting 'count' to 30
    }

    else (30-count.val().length == 0) //if value is == 0
    {
        $j("#charNum").text("submit is now enabled"); //print this
        $j("#submit").removeAttr('disabled'); // allow submit button
    {   

});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a large number of errors in your code. Since you're using jsFiddle, I'd suggest using the JSHint function and working through them next time.

To get it to function as you suggested, my final jQuery was:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j("#textArea").on("keyup keydown keypress", function(){ //captures all key input, not always necessary
    var count = $j(this); //you were missing 'var' and were using $ instead of $j

    if ($j(this).val().length <= 30 ) {
        $j("#charNum").text(30 - count.val().length); //you had an unmatched bracket here
    } else { //could not compare bracketed values as an else, use else if, or no if at all
        $j("#charNum").text("submit is now enabled");
        $j("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
    } //your closing bracket was back to front
});
```

Edit: Don't forget, if you want to limit text input, you can use the `maxlength` attribute for the textarea, set to the number of characters you want to limit it to. This works in all modern browsers and, as far as I recall, back to IE 7 or 8, I forget which.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textArea").on('keyup', function(){
     var th = $(this), val = $.trim(th.val()), chars = val.length;
     $j("#charNum").html(chars + ' of 30 entered');
     if(chars === 30){
        $("#submit").attr('enabled', true);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

you can use **jquery.limit** plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jquery-limit.googlecode.com/files/jquery.limit-1.2.source.js"></script>

<textarea name="value" id="value" style="width: 100%; height: 150px"></textarea>
<span id="charsLeft"></span> Characters left.

<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#value').limit('30', '#charsLeft');
</script>
```

Comment: Is that a jQuery function without an extra plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){

    $j("#textArea").keyup(function(){
        count = $j(this);
        $j("#charNum").text(30 - count.val().length);
        if (30-count.val().length == 0) {
            $j("#charNum").text("submit is now enabled");
            $j("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
        }   
    });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xc9JA/)